# Achieve object under another in <li> list

Tags: html, css

This is probably a newbie question but I'm not use to it and I really don't know how to achieve this...

I have to reproduce this [image]

The code is generated by smarty but it stay pretty clear :

```
<ul>
   {foreach from=$subs.subs item="sub"}
     <li><img src="{$sub.image}"/>
     <a href="{$sub.url}">{$sub.name}</a>
     </li>
   {/foreach}
</ul>
```

However the question is really simple, no matter what clear or float association I've tried I dont get this but something like this

[image]

Here is a little **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h0mv000/)**

I'm sure this is easy to do but somehow I don't manage to do it. I'll be glad to have a bit of help on this one; how shall I manage this ?

Comment: With float:left, have you specified width ?

Comment: Yeah images has max-width specified

Comment: Show generated HTML not the generating code! With css! Any one `<li>`!

Comment: min/max-width won't help here... add a specific with in <li> like width:100px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This CSS will help you a long way:

```
a {
 display: block; 
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Full code:

```css
a {
 display: block; 
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="" width=100 height = 100/>
    <a href="">Caption text thingy</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image text is positioned inline, next to the image, that is why youe are experiencing that issue. Simply add this in your css:

```
li img,li a{display:block;}
```

Here is a demo:

```css
img{ width:80px; height:80px}
li{display:inline-block;}
li img,li a{display:block;}
```

```html
<li>
    <img src=""/>
    <a href="">Your text</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src=""/>
    <a href="">Your text</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src=""/>
    <a href="">Your text</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src=""/>
    <a href="">Your text</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src=""/>
    <a href="">Your text</a>
</li>
```

Comment: check with inline-block :)

Comment: @Baldráni your fiddle has a missing `li{display:inline-block;}`,  check my demo